# Creating an xlsx file with API

Tags: java, xlsx

The error below occurs when I'm trying to create an xlsx file usig XSSF workbook. I've seen more answers on this for people, but it does not contain a single answer for my problem.

Just a snippet of my code that handles this (which is the direct cause of the error):

```
public static void Reader(File file) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xlsx)
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);        

    // Getting the Sheet at index zero
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

    for(int i = 1; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(j);

            switch(j) {
                case 0:
                    debiteurList.add(cell.toString());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    losnaamList.add(cell.toString());
                    break;
                case 5:
                    losadresList.add(cell.toString());
                    break;
                case 7:
                    lospostcodeList.add(cell.toString());
                    break;
                case 8:
                    losplaatsList.add(cell.toString());
                    break;
                case 9:
                    loslandList.add(cell.toString());
                    break;
                case 11:
                    totallinesList.add(cell.toString());
                    break;
                case 12:
                    opmerkingList.add(cell.toString());
                    break;
                case 14:
                    rijtypeList.add(cell.toString());
                    break;
                case 15:
                    beginlostijdList.add(cell.toString());
                    break;
                case 16:
                    eindlostijdList.add(cell.toString());
                    break;                      
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("successfully read xlsx");
    workbook.close();
}
```

This is the error:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
        at planning.pyxislijst.Reader.Reader(Reader.java)
        at planning.pyxislijst.Reader.Runner(Reader.java)
        at client.Client$4.actionPerformed(Client.java)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: I've tried using WorkbookFactory, that didn't seem to work either for some reason..

Comment: Note that WorkbookFactory did work for xls files, could it have anything to do with the fact that my xlsx license has expired and my xls didnt? It doesnt seem to be logic at all, but who knows, just trying to give you all the information i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you’re missing a dependency. Maybe https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.5.0

Comment: Thanks for your response, that could be the case. However, my IDE doesn't give any error and adding the jar file doesn't make a different (probably because it is not even used at the imports XD, which lines of code should be importing xml beans then?)

Comment: should I place the jar file inside a library folder?

Comment: using Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis) gave the error that im missing collections4 (NoClassDefFoundError), downloaded it and inserted it, but it still gives that same error.

Comment: I thank you for your answers. It seemed like commons-collections version 4.4.0 didnt have the valuedmaps, but upgrading to 4.4.1 worked :) Even though your answer wasn't exactly correct, you have helped me very very much!